# How can we get the list of crowdloan contributors?

Tags: crowdloan

After ending of crowdloan campaign. How we can fetch the contributor details?

Answer (score 2):

First you would need to know about the block height when your crowdloan started and ended and fetch all those blocks on either Kusama or Polkadot (depending upon where the crowdloan took place).

Then parse each block and look for `contribution` events originating on the `Crowdloan` pallet which indicates that the contribution took place to your parachain (based on your `paraId`).

*Note:* this would not fetch the contributors who contributed using third party platforms like `Bifrost`. I assume they transfer all their contributors' funds into their own wallet and make contribution from that single wallet.

This link might help you get started
: [Crowdloan contributions on Kusama](https://kusama.subscan.io/event?address=&module=crowdloan&event=contributed&startDate=&endDate=&startBlock=&endBlock=&timeType=date&version=9370)